# Lower bound for the probability of binomial variable to be less than her expectation

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Let $X$ a binomial variable of parameter $(N,p)$, with $0<p<0.5$
I would like to lower bound $\mathbb{P}\left(X <Np \right)$ by a constant ($\frac{1}{5}$ seems true and is enough for me).

Thank you by advance

Comment: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff-Ungleichung

Comment: Ich kenne diese Ungleichung, aber es ist nicht genug für mich (In meinem Problem delta ist null)

Comment: I found this paper which should imply what you want, but with maybe an unsatisfyingly-long proof. https://cs.nyu.edu/media/publications/binomial.pdf

Comment: Perhaps you can easily prove it by using that the median is either $\lfloor Np \rfloor$ or $\lceil Np \rceil$.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. As the reference given by user usul strongly suggests, the desired lower bound is nontrivial (in that referenced paper, the lower bound is given on the heavier, "non-strict" tail (but under less stringent conditions on $p$); see my answer for details on this).

Comment: @levgeni: There should be a bound for the probability that X takes a certain value e.g. by using Stirlings formula. Then one can combine it with the Chernoff bound for some $\delta>0$ to get the desired estimate.

Comment: Here is another reference for this sort of problem: "An Elementary Analysis of the Probability That a Binomial Random Variable Exceeds Its Expectation": https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.00519?context=cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma} 
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\PP}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}} 
\newcommand{\tf}{\widetilde{f}}$

Let $n:=N$. User usul gave in his comment a [reference](https://cs.nyu.edu/media/publications/binomial.pdf) to a result, which implies the exact lower bound, $1/4$, on $\PP(X\le np)$ for $p\in(0,1-\frac1n]$. Let us show here that the same lower bound holds under the following slightly better condition on $p$ (which can be shown optimal). Namely, let us show that 
\begin{equation*}
 \PP(X<np)\ge\tfrac14\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for
\begin{equation*}
 p\in\Big(0,1-\frac cn\Big],\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
 c:=\ln\frac43=0.28768\dots.\tag{3} 
\end{equation*}
Our proof appears to be significantly simpler than that in [reference](https://cs.nyu.edu/media/publications/binomial.pdf).

By Shevtsova's version of the [Berry--Esseen bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem), 
\begin{equation*}
 \PP(X<np)\ge \frac12-\ep,\quad\ep:=\frac{c_3}{\sqrt n}\Big(\frac\rho{\si^3}+c_2\Big), 
\end{equation*}
$\rho=q^3p+p^3q$, $\si=\sqrt{pq}$, $q:=1-p$, $c_3:=\frac{33554}{100000}$, $c_2=\frac{415}{1000}$. 
Since $\ep$ is a simple algebraic function of $p,n$, one can (algorithmically) solve a simple problem of real algebraic geometry to show that $\frac12-\ep$ is $\ge$ a certain algebraic number $0.25579\ldots>\frac14$ when $np\ge2$ and $nq\ge2$.

Therefore and because (2) can be rewritten (for $p\in(0,1)$) as $nq\ge c$, it remains to consider the following cases.

*Case 1:* $1<np\le2$ and $n\ge3$. Then 
\begin{equation*}
 \PP(X<np)=\PP(X\le1)=f_1(p):=f_1(p,n):=q^n + n q^{n - 1} p. 
\end{equation*}
We have $f_1'(p)=-(n-1) n q^{n-2} p<0$, and so, $f_1(p)$ is decreasing in $p$. So, here without loss of generality (wlog) $p=2/n$, and 
and 
\begin{equation*}
 \tilde f_1(n):=f_1(2/n,n)=\frac{3 n-2}{n-2}\,\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^n.  
\end{equation*}
Letting 
\begin{equation*}
 D\tilde f_1(n):=\tilde f'_1(n)\Big/\frac{\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^n \left(3 n^2-8 n+4\right)}{(n-2)^2}
 =\frac{\left(3 n^2-8 n+4\right) \ln\frac{n-2}{n}+6 n-8}{(n-2) (3 n-2)}, 
\end{equation*}
we have 
\begin{equation*}
 (D\tilde f_1)'(n)=-\frac{4 \left(3 n^2-4 n+4\right)}{(2-3 n)^2 (n-2)^2 n}<0.  
\end{equation*}
So, $D\tilde f_1$ is decreasing. Also, $D\tilde f_1(\infty-)=0$. So, $D\tilde f_1>0$ and hence $\tilde f_1$ is increasing, from $\tilde f_1(3)=\frac 7{27}=0.25925\dots>\frac14$. So, $\PP(X<np)>\frac14$ in Case 1.

*Case 2:* $0<np\le1$ and $n\ge2$. This case is similar to, and simpler than, Case 1. In this case the lower bound $\frac14$ is attained when $n=2$ and $p=1/2$.

*Case 3:* $1<nq\le2$ and $n\ge4$. This case is similar to, and slightly simpler than, Case 1. Note that $\PP(X<np)=1-\PP(X\ge n-nq)$, and here $nq$ is small. In this case the infimum of $\PP(X<np)$ is $67/256=0.26171\ldots>\frac14$, and it is attained "in the limit" when $n=4$ and $p=\frac34-$.

*Case 4:* $c\le nq\le1$ and $n\ge1$, where $c$ is as in (3). Then 
\begin{equation*}
 \PP(X<np)=1 - p^n\ge1 - p^{c/q}\ge\tfrac14. 
\end{equation*}

*Case 5:* $n\in\{1,2,3\}$. For each of these three values of $n$, $\PP(X<np)$ is piecewise polynomial in $p$ and thus is easily minimized, which allows us to conclude that in this case (1) holds as well.

Comment: I think the lower bound on the non-strict tail implies a lower bound on the strict tail by just lowering $p$ by $\epsilon$. Of course there is no problem giving a new / simpler argument in this more stringent  condition.

Comment: @WillSawin : Good point. On the other hand, it may be possible to extend this simpler argument to cover the less stringent condition on $p$. I'll check this out (so far, have been focused on answering the question as asked).

Comment: Indeed, by tweaking the previous argument, it is possible to cover the less stringent condition on $p$. In fact, our updated condition on $p$ is better than that in the referenced paper; moreover, this new condition is now optimal. The proof remains as simple as before, maybe even simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you Iosif, Usul, The proof seems a little bit hard for me, but I will look at it in details later, for now the references you gave it to me are enough. @ Will : your reasoning interests, me but I think it needs more restriction (like $(N,p) \neq (2,\frac{1}{2})$ )

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this problem a while ago, and wasn't completely satisfied with the published proof. In fact, I'll present a small poster in [Vilnius](http://ims-vilnius2018.com) in two weeks on a rather simple, different proof that generalises the result a bit. It does not involve any approximation at all! Rather, it derives the inequality by proving that the quantity is "sort of" monotone in $n$.

The basic building block of the proof is a result by [Hoeffding](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177728178) saying, for our purposes, that if $Y_1, \dotsc, Y_n$ are independent Bernoulli with $\mathbb{P}(Y_i(p) = 1) = p_i$, $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = k$, and $a \leq k \leq b$ then $$\mathbb{P}(a \leq \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \leq b) \geq \mathbb{P}(a \leq \operatorname{Bin}(n,k/n) \leq b).$$

Now $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,k/n)$ so that $\mathbb{E}(X) = n \cdot k/n = k$ can be written as $X = \sum_{i=1}^{n} I_i$ where $I_1, \dotsc, I_{n}$ are independent with $\mathbb{P}(I_i = 1) = k/n$. But we also have $X = \sum_{i=1}^{n} I_i + I'_{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} I_i + I''_{n+1} - 1$ where $I'_{n+1} = 0$ and $I''_{n+1} = 1$, in other words Bernoulli with success $0$ and Bernoulli with success $1$! By Hoeffding's result we therefore have
$$\mathbb{P}(X < k) = \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} I_i + I'_{n+1} < k) \leq \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Bin}(n+1,k/(n+1)) < k)$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X < k) = \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} I_i + I''_{n+1} - 1 < k) \leq \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Bin}(n+1,(k+1)/(n+1)) < k+1)$$

By iterating these inequalities you can identify the extremal case, where $n$ is as small as possible, directly! Indeed, the proof works for values other than the mean, which allows us to, for example, get analogous results for constant shifts away from the mean.

I recently discovered that the same idea was used by [Anderson and Samuels](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512976).